# Using Parse SDK in watchOS2

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, watchkit, watchos-2

I can't find how to use **`Parse` SDK in `watchOS2`**, does anyone know?

I used it in `watchOS` and it worked great, but now I can't do `Parse` queries in my `WatchKit Extension`s `InterfaceController` without getting errors:

```
// Query Parse
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"data"];
```

**Is this just not possible anymore?**

If not, has anyone had success using it in the `iPhone` app and then some workaround to use the `Parse` data in my `watchOS2` app?

How would you keep the iPhone app and Apple Watch app in parity though in case the iPhone app is not launched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Parse SDK for iOS on watchOS 2, because its code runs on Apple Watch device.

[Documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/)

> In watchOS 2, the extension runs on
>   the user’s Apple Watch instead of on the user’s iPhone, as was the
>   case in watchOS 1.

Simply implement your code in iOS app and communicate between iOS and watchOS2 via WCSession class. I did so.

Comment: What happens if a user opens the Watch before the iPhone app, does it have to go wake up the iPhone app to do the query?

Comment: I guess I'm just not understanding that since not native apps (watchOS) were able to run Parse in the extension, yet now that we have native apps which is great (watchOS2) somehow I'm able to do less by not being able to use Parse in the extension anymore.  Seems weird right?

Comment: If an iOS app is in background or foreground, you can send request from watch app to iOS. If the iOS app isn't launched, you can't (so you should display some appropriate message on watch device). [FYR](http://www.kristinathai.com/watchos-2-how-to-communicate-between-devices-using-watch-connectivity/)

Comment: How would you keep the iPhone app and Apple Watch app in parity though in case the iPhone app is not launched?  I don't know that there is any way to use NSURLSession with Parse.

Comment: You should use sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler: method from watchOS. This will wake your iOS app in background (even if the iOS app is not launched). And then you may want to run background task and do something (login to Parse, retrieve user data, etc).

Comment: @hiro_kimu How are you supposed to conform PFObject to NSCoding to be sent to the other side, as the data needs to be serializable?

Comment: @EridB I think Parse code (includes handling PFObject) should be implemented in iOS side only. I choose indispensable data from PFObject, make NSDictionary, and send it to watchOS.